# Limitations of ParametricNDSolve family w.r.t objective functions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

**Observation:**

I can see even for very simple modification in case of an scalar objective involving an definite integral in time `ParametricNDSolve` fails. Here is an example!

```
eqns = {y''[t] + y[t] == 3 a Sin[y[t]], y[0] == y'[0] == 1};
pfun =ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns,Integrate[y[s] - a s, {s, 0, 5}], {t, 0, 5}, {a},
Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> "ForwardSensitivity"}];
pfun[1.5]
```

> Meaningless output!

Same kind of output for `pfun'[1.5]` but from `pfun''[1.5]` onwards for higher derivatives we get numerical values which I guess are totally wrong.

However everything will be fine if one uses `Integrate[y[s], {s, 0, 5}]`! So I tried `{"ParametricSensitivity" -> "AdjointSensitivity"}` which is most suitable for integrated objective functions. Again failure but this time for both the cases. We get the following error

> ParametricNDSolveValue::adjsens: The adjoint sensitivity method cannot be used for the output function {t,0,5}. It can only be used for output functions that are at a particular time or are a definite integral over time. >>

I feel this is a major inconsistency of implementation internal. Using `Trace` I found some esoteric `Integrate`ImproperDump`` ` and ``Internal`DependsOnQ`.

**What should be `pfun[1.5]`:**

We know

```
Distribute[Integrate[y[s] - a s, {s, 0, 5}], Plus] === 
Integrate[-a s, {s, 0, 5}] + Integrate[y[s], {s, 0, 5}]
```

> True

So we first can find `pfun[1.5]` using

```
eqns = {y''[t] + y[t] == 3 a Sin[y[t]], y[0] == y'[0] == 1};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, 
Integrate[y[s], {s, 0, 5}], {t, 0, 5}, {a}, 
Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> "ForwardSensitivity"}];
(pfun[1.5] + Integrate[-a s, {s, 0, 5}]) /. a -> 1.5
```

> -7.86673

and the first order sensitivity will be

```
(pfun'[1.5] + D[Integrate[-a s, {s, 0, 5}], a]) /. a -> 1.5
```

> -7.87591

Crosschecking the first order sensitivity below!

```
fun1[aval_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[Block[{a = aval}, 
Evaluate@(y /. First@NDSolve[Evaluate@eqns, y, {t, 0, 5}])[t] -a t] , {t, 0, 5}];
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
ND[fun1[x], x, 1.5]
```

> -7.87604

Pretty much as expected.

**Question:**

- It will be great to know if we can use `ParametricNDSolve` family to find parameter dependency of integrated objective like the following: 
  $$ G(p)=\int_a^{b} g(y(s),s,p) \,ds$$
  where $g$ is a function of the dependent variable $y(s)$ of the underlying differential equation system and $p$ represents the parameter with respect to which the sensitivity $\frac{dG}{dp}$ is sought (i.e `a` in the above example).
- Also why `{"ParametricSensitivity" -> "AdjointSensitivity"}` fails in the above example?

For some math reference check [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.65.455&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

BR

Comment: What values would you have expected?

Comment: @ruebenko if `pfun[1.5]` is unevaluated and so is `pfun'[1.5]` then one needs to be really audacious to expect even anything  sensible for the higher derivatives. But M9 in this specific case returns values for the higher derivatives. That is not the kind of behavior one expects from a intelligent system.

Comment: what numerical values were you expecting; I'd like to verify my answer before giving it.

Comment: I get different results, so I am not going to post.

Comment: @ruebenko Sorry! I expect `-7.86673` for `pfun[1.5]`. I had a mistake in the previous comment.

Comment: That's what I get; I have a couple of meetings and I'll post sometime after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK,

```
eqns = {y''[t] + y[t] == 3 a Sin[y[t]], y[0] == y'[0] == 1};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, 
   Integrate[y[s] - a s, {s, 0, 5}], {t, 0, 5}, {a}
   (*,Method\[Rule]{"ParametricSensitivity"\[Rule]\"ForwardSensitivity"}*)];
pfun[1.5]
```

does not return 'meaningless' stuff but a symbolic integral. And in fact you have requested it to return an `Integrate`. So to evaluate it just call `N`.

```
N[pfun[1.5]]
(* -7.86673 *)
```

And the same holds for the derivatives. Now, you can not request an `NIntegrate` in `NDSolve`, since that would give messages during the function call since then the input to `NIntegrate` were then symbolic. And similar for the derivative. As to why the second derivative self evaluates, I do not know. If you feel passionate about it, you might report a bug to WRI.

For a sanity check we can use:

```
Block[{a = 1.5}, 
 eqns = {y''[t] + y[t] == 3 a Sin[y[t]], y[0] == y'[0] == 1}; 
 nds = NDSolveValue[eqns, y[t], {t, 0, 5}];
 NIntegrate[nds - a t, {t, 0, 5}]
 ]
(* -7.86673 *)
```

Using the

```
, Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> "AdjointSensitivity"}
```

gives a warning message:

```
(*
ParametricNDSolveValue::adjsens: "The adjoint sensitivity method cannot be used for the output function {t,0,5}. It can only be used for output functions that are at a particular time or are a definite integral over time."
*)
```

So only something like this is possible:

```
eqns = {y''[t] + y[t] == 3 a Sin[y[t]], y[0] == y'[0] == 1};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, 
   Integrate[y[1.5], {s, 0, 5}], {t, 0, 5}, {a}
   , Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> "AdjointSensitivity"}];
pfun[1.5]
```

I think `ParametricNDSolve` is quite a useful function and produces everything else then meaningless output.