# "ParametricSensitivity" in ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, options, documentation, undocumented

`"ParametricSensitivity"` is listed as a `Method` in the documentation for `ParametricNDSolve`, and the documentation goes on discuss `Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> None}`.  Also, question [30054](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30054/limitations-of-parametricndsolve-family-w-r-t-objective-functions/30109#30109) mentions a few other options for this method but without discussing them.  Where can I obtain additional information on `"ParametricSensitivity"`?  I have found none from searching this site or Google.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The choices allowed for `"ParametricSensitivity"` can be seen from the following error message

```
ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == 1, y[0] == a}, y[1], {t, 1}, a, 
  Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> "?"}];

 (* ParametricNDSolveValue::bdsmtd: Method ? for solution stage ParametricSensitivity 
    is not one of {Automatic, None, ForwardSensitivity, AdjointSensitivity}. >> *)
```

`None` means no sensitivities will be computed. The default method setting is `Automatic`, which will typically compute forward sensitivities, although `"AdjointSensitivity"` may be used in some cases, e.g. if the solution is only requested at a particular time.

In the important default case when `WorkingPrecision` is machine precision and no time integration method has been specified, *Mathematica* will use the built-in sensitivity solvers from the [SUNDIALS](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/main.html) suite, in particular the [CVODES](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/documentation/cvs_guide.pdf) or [IDAS](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/documentation/idas_guide.pdf) libraries for initial value ODE problems or DAE systems respectively. For some mathematical background on the methods used, I would recommend the following [paper](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/nsde/pubs/toms_cvodes_with_covers.pdf) and the references therein. Quoting from the introduction,

> The forward sensitivity
>   module in CVODES implements the simultaneous corrector method, as well as two flavors of
>   staggered corrector methods. Its adjoint sensitivity module provides a combination of checkpointing
>   and cubic Hermite interpolation for the efficient generation of the forward solution during the
>   adjoint system integration.

In cases when CVODES or IDAS cannot be used (e.g. explicit method specified or not a machine precision problem), sensitivities are computed by solving an augmented system that includes the sensitivity equations.

The `"ParametricSensitivity"` results are accessible to the user by asking for derivatives with respect to the parameters. Other numerical solvers in `Mathematica` (e.g. `FindRoot` or `FindMinimum`) will make automatic use of sensitivities, if available, in the same way: by requesting derivatives whenever needed by the underlying algorithm.

For additional examples, I would also mention the following [presentation](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8718/) from the 2012 Wolfram Technology Conference.

Comment: This answer provides very useful background information.  Thanks.  It also would be useful to know which is the default option (the documentation suggests that it is not `None`), how the `"ParametricSensitivity"` results are accessible to the user, and which other Mathematica functions utilize the results.  For instance, do `FindRoot`, NMinimize, etc. utilize the results when doing computations that involve varying parameters, as in [88061](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88061/using-parametricndsolve-and-nminimize-to-find-accurate-interplanetary-trajectory/88079#88079)

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for the accept; I've now tracked down a few more details and slightly expanded the answer.

Comment: What a great trick for obtaining the list of `Method` options.  Many thanks for the thorough answer.