# Unexpected Behavior of Parametric Sensitivity in ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, bugs, numerics

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and continuing through 11.3**

Submitted as CASE:3916971

---

While exploring alternative methods of solving [33538](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151089/1063), I encountered difficulties with the parametric sensitivity capability of `ParametricNDSolveValue`.  (Useful background on parametric sensitivity is provided [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92277/1063) and [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8718/).)  Specifically, for

```
r0 = 1/10000; inf = 50; ξ = 15/10; n = 1;
pa = 172416/390625; pf = 5298661942732265830186933/7730236542592271015625000;

numSol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {r D[1/r D[A[r], r], r] - ξ^2 F[r]^2 (A[r] - 1) == 0,
     1/r D[r D[F[r], r], r] - n^2/r^2 F [r] (A[r] - 1)^2 - 1/2 F[r] (F[r]^2 - 1) == 0,
     A[r0] == a r0^2 - If[n == 1, f^2 r0^n ξ^2/8, 0], 
     F[r0] == f r0^n (1 - (1 + 4 a n^2) r0^2/(8 (n + 1))), 
     A'[r0] == 2 a r0 - If[n == 1, r0^3 f^2 ξ^2/2, 0], 
     F'[r0] == f r0^(n - 1) (n - (2 + n) (1 + 4 a n^2) r0^2/(8 (1 + n))),
     WhenEvent[A'[r] < 0 || F'[r] < 0 || A[r] > 1 || F[r] > 1, "StopIntegration"]}, 
    {A, F}, {r, r0, inf}, {a, f}];
```

the domain of integration changes when the sensitivity of the solution to infinitesimal variation of the values of the parameters is determined.

```
numSol[a, f] /. {a -> pa, f -> pf};
(First@%)["Domain"][[1, 2]]
D[numSol[a, f], a] /. {a -> pa, f -> pf};
(First@%)["Domain"][[1, 2]]
D[numSol[a, f], f] /. {a -> pa, f -> pf};
(First@%)["Domain"][[1, 2]]
numSol[a, f] /. {a -> pa, f -> pf};
(First@%)["Domain"][[1, 2]]
(* 6.21431 *)
(* 6.05906 *)
(* 6.05906 *)
(* 6.05906 *)
```

This change does not occur, if the sensitivity determination is not performed.  To see this, again execute the code defining `numSol`, and then execute

```
numSol[a, f] /. {a -> pa, f -> pf}
(First@%)["Domain"][[1, 2]]
numSol[a, f] /. {a -> pa, f -> pf}
(First@%)["Domain"][[1, 2]]
(* 6.21431 *)
(* 6.21431 *)
```

This strange behavior is exacerbated, when `WorkingPrecision` is set explicitly.  For instance,

```
numSol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {r D[1/r D[A[r], r], r] - ξ^2 F[r]^2 (A[r] - 1) == 0,
     1/r D[r D[F[r], r], r] - n^2/r^2 F [r] (A[r] - 1)^2 - 1/2 F[r] (F[r]^2 - 1) == 0,
     A[r0] == a r0^2 - If[n == 1, f^2 r0^n ξ^2/8, 0], 
     F[r0] == f r0^n (1 - (1 + 4 a n^2) r0^2/(8 (n + 1))), 
     A'[r0] == 2 a r0 - If[n == 1, r0^3 f^2 ξ^2/2, 0], 
     F'[r0] == f r0^(n - 1) (n - (2 + n) (1 + 4 a n^2) r0^2/(8 (1 + n))),
     WhenEvent[A'[r] < 0 || F'[r] < 0 || A[r] > 1 || F[r] > 1, "StopIntegration"]}, 
    {A, F}, {r, r0, inf}, {a, f}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision];
```

in which case the calls to `numSol` listed above return

```
(* 6.214311927593723 *)
(* 7.462342033621696 *)
```

> ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At r == 0.0001`15.954589770191003, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

```
(* 0.0001000000000000000 *)
(* 0.0001000000000000000 *)
```

The computations were performed with version 11.1.1 and also with 10.4.1 on Windows 10 (64 bit).  My specific questions are,

1. Is this a bug?
2. Is there a work-around?

Comment: In v9.0.1, `"Domain"` seems not to change in the first case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqKkt.png and only changes slightly in the second case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tPAO.png , I think it's a backslide at least. This might be related to [this issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21262/1871) so try the workaround there?

Comment: @xzczd  Thank you for your advice.  I tried `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}`, as you suggested, but it did not help.  Also, the bug described in the linked question purportedly has been fixed in 11.1.1.  I plan to submit this as a bug.

Comment: @ilian  You kindly answered my earlier question about parametric sensitivity.  I would appreciate your thoughts about the behavior shown in the current question.  Thanks.

Comment: I would say it is a bug, based on the description... unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce it on several Windows machines. Could you post (or send to support if preferable) some details about your CPU?

Comment: @ilian  There was a typo in `pf`, now corrected.  (I had dropped the first digit in the numerator.)  Please try again to reproduce my result.  Probably, the value of `pf` matters a lot, because this is a separatrix computation.  The correct value of `pf` allows integration far along the separatrix, where tiny changes in the initial conditions (and presumably anything else) can result in big changes to the output.  In contrast, the earlier incorrect value of `pf` scarcely allowed the integration to reach the separatrix, so any results it returned were fairly insensitive to initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you, now I can confirm the same behavior. A bug report has been opened, but I am not aware of a workaround for the moment.

Comment: Bug still present in MMA 11.2.0