# What are the valid options for the "ParametricCaching" option in ParametricNDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, options, implementation-details, undocumented

I am using `ParametricNDSolve` as part of the calculation of an objective function for an optimization, so I am trying to strike a balance between memory usage and speed.  The documentation notes that the settings for `"Method"`, `"ParametricCaching"` and `"ParametricSensitivity"` can affect these things.  But the only options mentioned there are `Automatic` and `None`.  Are there any others?  In particular, the documentation states that

> The default is to cache the most recently computed solution.

Presumably this is the behavior under `Automatic`.  Is there a way to cache more than just the most recently computed solution?

---

[This previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92277/parametricsensitivity-in-parametricndsolve) discusses the options for `ParametricSensitivity`, but trying the same trick there returns an unexpected response:

```
ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == 1, y[0] == a}, y[1], {t, 1}, a, 
  Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> "?"}];

(* ParametricNDSolveValue::bdsmtd: Method ? for solution stage ParametricSensitivity is not one of {Automatic,None}. *)
```

I'm not sure why this trick would return options for `ParametricSensitivity`, unless this is a bug in the error-handling code and these are actually the available options for `ParametricCaching`.