# FindRoot changes results from ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs

I solve numerically an equation, and I get the expected behaviour like the following graph

[image]

But if I use `FindRoot` to get the roots before plotting, the plot of my solution changes drastically:

[image]

This is the code I am using

```
σs = .18;
{α2, mc} = {-0.1185, 1.27`};
bc[r_] = AiryAi[(-e mc + mc r σs)/(mc σs)^(2/3)];
inf = 20;
usol = ParametricNDSolve[{-(1/mc)*D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (α2/r + σs*r)*u[r] == e*u[r], 
    u[inf] == bc[inf], u'[inf] == bc'[inf]}, u, {r, 10^-10, inf}, e][[1, 2]]

Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5}]

FindRoot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 2}]

Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I can confirm this weird (and in my opinion buggy) behaviour in v12.3, v13.0 and v14.0. The reason for this is that `ParametricNDSolve` uses [caching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252623/does-mathematica-cache-the-interpolating-function-from-parametricndsolve), and `FindRoot`  seems to be evaluating the function differently, and repopulating the cache with "wrong"/less accurate values. You can do `ParametricNDSolve[..., Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None}]`, but I believe this should be fixed by developers, nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm using Mathematica v14.0 but even using the ParametricNDSolve[..., Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None}] remains buggy, but at least now I know why, I hope it will be fixed in the next versions.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, you have to also turn off caching the derivative `Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None, "ParametricSensitivity" -> None}`. This should work now :)

Comment: This absolutely shouldn't happen and should be reported as a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the culprit is differentiating `usol[p][10^-10]`. It looks like numerical ill-conditioning. However, I don't think differentiation should affect the numerics of the undifferentiated solution. So report it to WRI.

```
\[Sigma]s = .18;
{\[Alpha]2, mc} = {-0.1185, 1.27`};
bc[r_] = AiryAi[(-e  mc + mc  r  \[Sigma]s)/(mc  \[Sigma]s)^(2/3)];
inf = 20;
usol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-(1/mc)*
       D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (\[Alpha]2/r + \[Sigma]s*r)*u[r] == e*u[r], 
    u[inf] == bc[inf], u'[inf] == bc'[inf]}, u, {r, 10^-10, inf}, e];

p1 = Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5}];
D[usol[p][10^-10], {p}] /. p -> 0;  (*** <--- N.B.--- ***)
p2 = Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5}, PlotStyle -> Orange];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

**Fix one:**

Don't allow differentiation (with respect to `e`) in `ParametricNDSolve[]`:

```
usol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-(1/mc)*
      D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (\[Alpha]2/r + \[Sigma]s*r)*u[r] == e*u[r], 
   u[inf] == bc[inf], u'[inf] == bc'[inf]}, u, {r, 10^-10, inf}, e, 
  Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> None}]
```

**Fix two:**

Prevent differentiation (with respect to `e`) in `FindRoot`:

```
obj[p_?NumericQ] := usol[p][10^-10];
FindRoot[obj[p], {p, 2}]
```

**Fix three:**

Avoid differentiation (with respect to `e`) in `FindRoot` by using the secant method:

```
FindRoot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 2, 2.1}]
```

**Fix four:**

High precision integration (lower truncation error):

```
\[Sigma]s = .18;
{\[Alpha]2, mc} = {-0.1185, 1.27`};
bc[r_] = AiryAi[(-e  mc + mc  r  \[Sigma]s)/(mc  \[Sigma]s)^(2/3)];
inf = 20;
usol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-(1/mc)*
       D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (\[Alpha]2/r + \[Sigma]s*r)*u[r] == e*u[r], 
    u[inf] == bc[inf], u'[inf] == bc'[inf]}, u, {r, 10^-10, inf}, e, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 15];

p1 = Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5}];
D[usol[p][10^-10], {p}] /. p -> 0;
p2 = Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5}, PlotStyle -> Orange];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Note slight difference in plots for `0 < p < 0.1`.

**Fix five:**

High precision numerics (lower round-off error):

```
\[Sigma]s = .18`32;
{\[Alpha]2, mc} = {-0.1185`32, 1.27`32};
bc[r_] = AiryAi[(-e  mc + mc  r  \[Sigma]s)/(mc  \[Sigma]s)^(2/3)];
inf = 20;
usol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-(1/mc)*
       D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (\[Alpha]2/r + \[Sigma]s*r)*u[r] == e*u[r], 
    u[inf] == bc[inf], u'[inf] == bc'[inf]}, u, {r, 10^-10, inf}, e, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 32, PrecisionGoal -> 6];

p1 = Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5`32}, 
   PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], WorkingPrecision -> 32];
D[usol[p][10^-10], {p}] /. p -> 0;
p2 = Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5`32}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 32];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The only difference `usol :=` instead of `usol =`.

```
σs = .18;
{α2, mc} = {-0.1185, 1.27`};
bc[r_] = AiryAi[(-e mc + mc r σs)/(mc σs)^(2/3)];
inf = 20;
usol := ParametricNDSolve[{-(1/mc)*D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (α2/r + σs*r)*u[r] == e*u[r], 
    u[inf] == bc[inf], u'[inf] == bc'[inf]}, u, {r, 10^-10, inf}, e][[1, 2]]

Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5}]

FindRoot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 2}]

Plot[usol[p][10^-10], {p, 0, 2.5}]
```

---

[image]

Decide on your preference which definition you use, here are timings for original version with `=`, @Domen's version with `=` and `Method` and last version with `:=`.

```
Clear[usol1, usol2, usol3]
σs = .18;
{α2, mc} = {-0.1185, 1.27`};
bc[r_] = AiryAi[(-e mc + mc r σs)/(mc σs)^(2/3)];
inf = 20;

usol1 = ParametricNDSolve[{-(1/mc)*D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (α2/r + σs*r)*u[r] == e*u[r], 
    u[inf] == bc[inf], u'[inf] == bc'[inf]}, u, {r, 10^-10, inf}, e][[1, 2]]

usol2 = ParametricNDSolve[{-(1/mc)*D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (α2/r + σs*r)*u[r] == e*u[r], 
    u[inf] == bc[inf], u'[inf] == bc'[inf]}, u, {r, 10^-10, inf}, e, Method->{"ParametricCaching"->None,"ParametricSensitivity"->None}][[1, 2]]

usol3 := ParametricNDSolve[{-(1/mc)*D[u[r], {r, 2}] + (α2/r + σs*r)*u[r] == e*u[r], 
    u[inf] == bc[inf], u'[inf] == bc'[inf]}, u, {r, 10^-10, inf}, e][[1, 2]]

Print["usol="]
Table[usol1[q][10^-10], {q, 0, 2.5, 0.001}]; // Timing
Table[usol1[q][10^-10], {q, 0, 2.5, 0.001}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Print["usol= with method parameters"]
Table[usol2[q][10^-10], {q, 0, 2.5, 0.001}]; // Timing
Table[usol2[q][10^-10], {q, 0, 2.5, 0.001}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Print["usol:="]
Table[usol3[q][10^-10], {q, 0, 2.5, 0.001}]; // Timing
Table[usol3[q][10^-10], {q, 0, 2.5, 0.001}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

---

[image]

Comment: This undermines the core idea of `ParametricNDSolve`, namely that you don't have to reevaluate `NDSolve` for every value of parameter.

Comment: But turning off cashing like you suggest contradicts your assertion.